# TypeScript anonymous function

Tags: javascript, typescript, anonymous-function

What is the TypeScript equivalent of this JavaScript?

```
(function() { 
    /* code here */ 
})();
```

I have tried this

```
() => {
    /* code here */
}
```

But this produces

```
(function() {
    /* code here */
});
```

I need the extra set of parenthesis at the end to perform an execution of the anonymous function.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
(() => {
    /* code here */
})();
```

or simply use the JavaScript (which is equally valid TypeScript)

```
(function() { 
    /* code here */ 
})();
```

... depending whether you want to capture `this` using the fat arrow.

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=%28%28%29%20=%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20/*%20code%20here%20*/%0A%7D%29%28%29;%0A%0A%28function%28%29%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20/*%20code%20here%20*/%20%0A%7D%29%28%29;).